# AS3 Dynamically change / swap bitmapdata from a bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata

The Question :

I have a dynamically loaded image. It's the background of a site. After 10 seconds, I want to swap out that image with a new image!

The Thoughts :

I had thought this would be a simple enough process.

```
var BGbmd:BitmapData = new backgroundBitmapData(); // from library
var BG:Bitmap = new Bitmap( BBbmd );
    BG.width = stage.stageWidth; //save portrait vs landscape for later...
    BG.scaleY = BG.scaleX;
    BG.smoothing = true;
addChild( BG );
```

I figured I'd be able to just change the BGbmd to something else and it would update :

```
function changeBackground() {
    BGbmd = new secondBackgroundBitmapData(); // from Library
}
```

or something to that extent - but no! nothing changes! it appears I have to remove the child and re-add it which is a pain in the butt because i'd have to keep track of the childIndex…

The Outreach :
I'm really hopping that there's some magical function or method that I'm just not able to find that will allow me to easily find swap out bitmapdatas… maybe you'll know!

Thank you all so much!
-Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bitmap data inside the Bitmap.

```
BG.bitmapData = new secondBackgroundBitmapData();
```

The `Bitmap` is the thing on the stage, and it holds onto a reference to the `BitmapData` itself -- not the variable its assigned to. So you need to change the `Bitmaps` internal state to switch out the images.

Comment: GAHHH… i new it was a method like that! Thank you so much 32bitkid!